# Unity5 How can I create this particle effect

Tags: c#, unity

I have been trying to replicate this particle effect that moves with the mouse:

https://my.pottermore.com/patronus

I have got close with the following settings

[image]

but I can't get the movement of the particles to be the same or to have to same intense white glow. It's like they have random direction from the center of the cursor but depending on the mouse speed it's like they have spread out more instead of being clustered on the mouse (hard to explain).

Does anyone know how I would achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

It is really difficult to say from just looking at only the settings, but from looking at what you want versus what you've set up, I think your issue is the `force over lifetime`.

Try using negative values instead of positive values. If you pay really close attention to the particle effect on the website the particles suck inward to a center point and then blow out from the other side. I think that change will get you closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As a Shape use Cone and than play with the Angle and Radius till you get the result you need

Comment: That doesn't help at all, the question is regarding the effect the particles have when the mouse moves.

Comment: OK, so you want the particles to follow the mouse?